# Using ant to start forked java process

Tags: java, linux, ant

I have this build xml for ant:

```
<project>
  <target name="JSCover-start">
     <java jar="/root/JSCover/target/dist/JSCover-all.jar" fork="true" spawn="true">
        <arg value="-ws"/>
     </java>
     <waitfor maxwait="5" maxwaitunit="second" checkevery="250" checkeveryunit="millisecond" timeoutproperty="failed">
        <http url="http://localhost:8080/jscoverage.html"/>
    </waitfor>
    <fail if="failed"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

It builds fine but the process is not started.

The below starts the server perfectly fine:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /root/JSCover/target/dist/JSCover-all.jar -ws
```

Comment: Check out https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html

Comment: Are you running both commands as the same user (i.e. will the ant process have permission to listen on that port)?

Comment: How do you know that the process doesn't start?

Answer (score 0):

The posted code looks correct, so the issue is probably something else. Try this:

1. Enable debug/verbose output of `JSCover-all.jar`
2. Remove `fork="true" spawn="true"` since these options might redirect stdout/stderr to `/dev/null` which means you won't see any errors that `JSCover-all.jar` tries to tell you about.
3. Run `ant` with `-debug` to see what it tries to do; maybe that will give you a hint.

From my experience as a developer, my first guess would be that

a) the port isn't available (another server is already using it) or
b) your service binds to `*:8080`, i.e. the **public** IP address of your computer while the test tries to connect to `localhost`. Those are not the same.